# Best practice to handle Accepting Changeset without affecting the Local Changes

Tags: rational-team-concert

Generally, If we get any Incoming Changes will accept it and the incoming files will merge with the Local changes and the local files will modify. In other words, Incoming files will come with the conflicts in same file/line. We have to accept the incoming changes and we have to modify to local changes. Is there any best practice to handle Incoming changes and How to handle the Accepting Changeset without affecting the Local Changes.

Answer (score 0):

The general policy regarding change sets is detailed in "[Managing change sets in RTC](http://blog.royalcyber.com/devops/managing-change-sets-in-rtc/)".

If there is any conflict, the best practice is to determine if said conflicts are:

- the result of a concurrent work which should not happen again: you resolve the conflict and move on
- the result of systemic repeated concurrent work, in which case it is best to work on separate stream, not just separate workspaces on the same stream.